# Time optimal control with method of successive approximations in GEKKO

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I have a simple time optimal control problem that I am able to solve in GEKKO using the IPOPT optimizer. My goal is to re-implement this problem solving it with the method of successive approximations (MSA).

Here's the code I use to solve the problem with IPOPT:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
 
# set up the gekko model
m = GEKKO()
 
# set up the time (minimize the time with time scaling)
m.time = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
 
# set up the variables
POSITION = m.Var(value=0, ub=330, lb=0)
VELOCITY = m.Var(value=0, ub=33, lb=0)
 
# set up the value we modify over the horizon
tf = m.FV(value=500, lb=0.1)
tf.STATUS = 1
 
# set up the MV
u = m.Var(integer=True, lb=-2, ub=1)
 
# set up the equations
m.Equation(POSITION.dt() / tf == VELOCITY)
m.Equation(VELOCITY.dt() / tf == u)

# terminal constraint on POSITION
mask = np.zeros_like(m.time)
mask[-1] = 1
mask = m.Param(mask)
m.Equation(mask * (POSITION - 300) >= 0)
 
# set the objective
m.Minimize(tf)
 
# set up the options
m.options.IMODE = 6     # optimal control
m.options.SOLVER = 3    # IPOPT
 
# solve
m.solve(disp=False)
 
# print the time
print("Total time taken: " + str(tf.NEWVAL))
 
# plot the results
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(np.linspace(0,1,100)*tf.NEWVAL, POSITION, label='Position')
plt.plot(np.linspace(0,1,100)*tf.NEWVAL, VELOCITY, label='Velocity')
plt.ylabel('Z')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(np.linspace(0,1,100)*tf.NEWVAL, u, label=r'$u$')
plt.ylabel('u')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

From what I know, MSA is composed of 3 steps, that keep iterating until convergence:

1. Forward integration of state variable x, with fixed control u(t) and having x(0).
2. Backward integration of costate variable lambda, with fixed trajectory x(t). fixed control u(t) and having lambda(T).
3. Find control u*(t) minimizing/maximixing the Hamiltonian, with trajectory x(t) and costate lambda(t) found in previous two steps.

The problem I'm facing is that I need to find a control s.t. it respect the constraints and brings the position to 300 in the shortest time possible. So, already in the first step (forward integration), for how long do I simulate the sistem with fixed control?

Thank you in advance for the help :)